# Google font Rendering issue with ie7 and 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

I am using Open Sans and Open Sans Light font in my site.
And below is the googleapis font link which I am rendering from google fonts.
I want to use Open Sans Light and Open Sans font in some of the text.
If i choose open sans 300,400,600.
and use font name in the class and add  font-weight:300 for light and 400 for regular 
it doesn't work for ie7 and 8. It shows the big font on ie 7.

but by using font-weight related to the font styling works fine for other browsers.
Need help to fix this for ie7 and 8.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: You will need `.eot`, take a look at Font Squirrel

Answer (score 0):

With Google fonts you won't be able to solve this problem.

The problem is that IE7/8 understands only

`font-weight:700` which it interprets as equivalent of `font-weight:bold`

and

`font-weight:400` which it interprets as equivalent of `font-weight:normal`.

A solution to this is to serve a separate font file to IE7/8 which contains the desired font face weight - google fonts foes not offer this kind of fallback - but it is very nicely solved with Typekit, which than let's you use this kind of crossbrowser font face rule:

```
  font-family: "proxima-nova-n6", "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
```

The first declaration - `"proxima-nova-n6"` - provides a fallback for IE7/8 for a weight of 600.

If you want to solve this without paying for a service, you will have to create separate font files containing different font width - upload them to [fontsquirell](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and generate the complete set of formats needed to cover all the browsers. Take care with licenses - not all font's are free to embed on web.